# Ubuntu on Samsung Chromebook 2 boots to Chrome OS

Tags: chromebook

I successfully installed Ubuntu 14.04 but it boots to OS (dev mode) and I don't know how to switch to Ubuntu. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> forward/backward doesn't work. Please help!

Comment: Please provide more information. Did you use Crouton, Chroubuntu, or the official version of Ubuntu? Can you post a link to the instructions you followed?

Answer (score 0):

We are running Chromium + Ubuntu 13.10 on a Samsung 11.6" Chromebook, model 500C12-K01.  To switch I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>forward</kbd>.  By "forward" I mean the key labelled <kbd>F2</kbd> on most computers.

I set up the Chromebook following Ben Schoon's article  at http://itechtriad.com/articles/2014/7/21/how-to-install-minecraft-on-a-chromebook. He says you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>forward</kbd> to switch, which is different that works on my install.  I figured out the correct commands on my system by carefully readings the output messages that flash by during the installation.